# how to find and delete multiple files in bash/linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have directories with sub directories containing `.srt` files. I need to go through the directories and delete them all. I know how to find them like so:

```
find ./directory -name *.srt
```

but I'm not sure how to pipe them to `rm`.

Comment: First of all you should quote `*.srt` to avoid shell globbing. Without the quotes it will work as you expect only when there are no `*.srt` files in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a little bit tricky:

```
find ./directory -name "*.srt" -exec rm {}  \;
```

Comment: it'd be nicer to use -delete

Comment: `-exec rm {} \;` spawns `rm` for every file. `-exec rm {} +` removes many files at once; `-delete` is the best because it doesn't create new processes, I believe.

Comment: @djsmiley2k though `-delete` isn't strictly portable, though BSD and GNU both support it.  It isn't specified in POSIX though, but if you've got it that's the way to go

Comment: Here's what I used and it worked fine. Thanks to all those who answered and commented:        `find TV_Recordings/ -name "*.srt" -delete`