# 'find' utility does not output all files when using wildcards

Tags: find, wildcards

Running:

```
$find . -name *.exe
```

gives:

```
./MakeItSo_1.2.2/MakeItSo_1.2.2/MakeItSo.exe
./MakeItSo.exe
```

but those are not the only exe files in the directory. For example, running

```
$find . -name ATLTester.exe
```

gives:

```
./Debug/ATLDmoVexaTester.exe
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of shell [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). Try:

```
find . -name "*.exe"
```

When not quoted, `*.exe` expands to all `*.exe` files in the current directory, unless there are none. It so happens you have just one such a file there, so your original command was in fact:

```
find . -name MakeItSo.exe
```

If you had no `*.exe` files in the current directory then shell globbing wouldn't occur, `find` would get `*.exe` argument literally and your command would work as you expected. On the other hand if you had more than one file with this extension, they all would be given as arguments to `find` and this would lead to syntax error.

Comment: Well spotted! I puzzled over the question for a while, before I scrolled down to your answer.

Comment: @AFH Compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217706/432690) from few hours ago and my comment there. At first I thought like 'déjà vu?' here.

Comment: Thanks for the reference: I'd never noticed the `-delete` option, so it's nice to know that I'm never too old to learn.

Comment: But the OP also said he had `ATLTester.exe` in the same directory.

Comment: @Hashim In a *subdirectory*. This makes a huge difference.

Comment: Ah, nice catch.