# Find all directories that contain a certain character and print them out

Tags: bash, find

I need to find all directories which contain a certain character in their name and print them out.

So if i have the directories:

```
abc cde fgh
```

And I search for "c" I should get:

```
abc 
cde
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The following commands perform the required query:

```
find -name "*c*" -type d
```

- starts with the current directory (no need to specify directory in case of current directory)
- `-name "*c*"` - with name contains the letter `c`
- `-type d` - which are a directory

You can run the command on other directory (`/full/path/to/dir`) using:

```
find /full/path/to/dir -name "*c*" -type d
```

More info [nixCraft find command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-a-directory-linux-command/)

Comment: Note: in this case `-print` is unnecessary, it's the default action. Also, to start with the current directory only, one may not give a path because `.` is the default path. Good answer though. Wildcards may be a trap like in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690), quoting them is very important here.

Comment: @DevidDemetz - great :-)

Comment: I have another question. If id now like to rename the the directory name. like the "c" that i searched for should become an "a". how would i do that

Comment: @DevidDemetz - if you have a new question - how to 1) find directories with specific pattern and 2) replace the directories name with a specific pattern - please open a new question for that.

Comment: On MacOS it doesn't work when you leave out the path. `find . -name "*c*" -type d` worked for me.

Comment: you might prefer "-iname" if you want case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

If [`globstar`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) is enabled you can use this

```
for d in **/*c*/; do echo $d; done
```

The first `**` will match any arbitrary subdirectory paths. Then `*c*/` with match folders with the c character in it

If it's not enabled you can enable it with [`shopt -s globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)

> - globstar
>
>   - If set, the pattern `**` used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in `find -name "*c*" -type d -maxdepth 1`; do
      echo $dir
done
```

Comment: Whilst this may indeed work, it would be good to [edit] your answer and add some explanation...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133896)