# How do i rename all directories containing a specific character

Tags: bash, find, rename

So I asked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1218163/find-all-directories-that-contain-a-certain-character-and-print-them-out/1218165?noredirect=1#comment1779548_1218165) on how to find a directory that contains a specific character.

Now I'd like to change that character to something else (not the whole name just that one character)

Example:

```
find "a"
     aaa 
     bab
replace with "c"
     ccc
     bcb
```

How do I do that?

This is the code I have atm

```
read -p "find what character: " findwhat
find . -name "*$findwhat*" -type d -print
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use `rename` (aka `prename`). To replace `_` with `-`:

```
rename 's/_/-/g' dirname
```

(the `g` replaces all occurrences. Omit it if you only want to replace one occurrence)

Combining this with your `find` statement:

```
find . -name "*$findwhat*" -type d -execdir rename "s/$findwhat/$replacewith/g" {} \;
```

You might need to modify this to get the variable substitution to work correctly.

<sub>Note: The `{}` tells `-execdir/-exec` where to insert the filename in the command; the `;` tells it where the commands ends - and you need to escape it with `\` because otherwise the shell will treat it as a command separator.</sub>

Comment: thanks it works. but why do i need that {} and backslash?

Comment: The `{}` tells `-execdir/-exec` where to insert the filename in the command; the `;` tells it where the commands ends - and you need to escape it with ``\`` because otherwise the shell will treat it as a command separator.

Comment: Added it to the answer :)