# WildCards corrupts Copy`s output file when an output name is specified

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, wildcards, syntax

`copy` create's an almost empty (1K) file when a wildcard (*?) is used in the source & an output name is specified.

`copy /D /V *?ample.png %homepath%/example.png`

it works for some file types (.txt .rtf)
`copy /D /V *?ample.txt %TEMP%\example.txt`

interestingly wildcards in both the source & the destination fixes this,
 `copy "*xample.pdf" "%TEMP%/*xample.pdf"`
but messes up the file name, it be comes: *le.pdfxample.pdf*

is this a Bug or bad *syntax*? i'm stumped.

i'm on Windows 7 x86_64
related questions
[Using wildard with DOS COPY command corrupts destination file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704333/using-wildard-with-dos-copy-command-corrupts-destination-file)

[How do I copy a file using a wildcard in Windows without appending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048552/how-do-i-copy-a-file-using-a-wildcard-in-windows-without-appending)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a (mis-)used feature.
My Windown 10 `help copy` says:

> To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files
>   for source (using wildcards or file1+file2+file3 format).

If the file format doesn't support simply concatenated source files, it's up to the user to keep this in mind.

Also [Bali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14704511/6811411) to your first link fully answers your question.

A different workaround if there is only one source file with unclear name is:

```
for %A in (*?ample.png) Do copy "%A"  "%homepath%/example.png"
```

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. A `*` means _0 or more_ chars; `*?` means _one or more_ chars, which is a significant and useful difference.

Comment: `Copy` should not assume it's "appending" files in this case,
 it should check & if multiple Binary files are given, exit with an _error: Cannot concatenated Binary files_.



Microsoft, so misguided

Answer (score 1):

`copy` must know i file's type: "ASCII text" **`/A`** or a "Binary file" **`/B`**

A Binary file **`/B`** is assumed unless  you are combining files.
but windows "assumes"  when you put wildcards in the source & specify an output name you are combining files,  & use's the "ASCII text" interpreter, so making a 1K empty file.

So the **`/B`**  Parameter (Indicates a binary file)
 must be used  when using wildcards in the source with an output name 
specified,
 on all non "ASCII text" file's.

`copy /B /D /V *?ample.png %homepath%/example.png`

Call it a Bug, a stupid Microsoft feature, but thats the way it is.

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx)

Comment: /B has long ago changed to mean 'copy the link and not its target'.  /B lost meaning in DOS 6 and reappeared in its new form in Windows 95, if my memory is correct.   The above bug is present in Windows 7/x86.

Comment: But I had to try the /B switch after reading your comment.  You have found the source of the bug!  If only we had the source code.... Seems like the MS team is not very good at cleaning up code.  I wionder how many of these gems are still lurking around.

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your use of wildcards...  You're copying (potentially) many files into one single target, overwriting this poor file many times quite uselessly :).  But, it did bring out this interesting 'feature'.  I'm tempted to bring out my DOS floppies to check if the bug is that old.

I congratulate you on finding this interesting bug in DIR!  The copied file end up corrupted.  It's very consistent, does not depend on the /D /V switches, and only happens when overwriting the same file over and over again.  The bug does not appear when using xcopy, which is good news for all windows users.

Comment: "_One issue with your use of wildcards_"....... Agreed, but that's not the issue [here](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/680625),
 & i disagree with "...happens when overwriting the same file...." happens the **first** time, every time. & thanks!

Comment: I've played with it for a good 20 minutes this morning....   using willdcards for both input and output works like a charm under win7/x86.  And the help for /B is "copy link as a link and not as its target" in a regular  cmd window, but not, as I've jusrt checked in a VS2008 cmd session.

Comment: Sorry, I'll never get used to the return key behaviour on this site.

Comment: There seems to be a good many things yet to discover about copy...  I wonder if the new VS2017 sdks provide their own version as well,  To be continued...

Comment: The bug it were `copy` thinks "Binary files" are "ASCII text" file's when wildcards are use in the source & you specify a destination  name, thats it!

Comment: "And the help for /B is "copy link as a link and not as its target"....
it's just you, everywhere else it's **/b**   : Indicates a binary file.