# How to find a file with partially known path? `find -path` doesn't seem to work

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have a file located at `folderA/folderB/myFile`. This however is a relative address and I don't know where on my computer it is. `myFile` has a very generic name and searching just for it will give me hundreds of results. So I am trying to search for the entire path.

After looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849837/linux-how-to-find-specific-files-in-specific-folders), I tried these options:

```
find / -path folderA/folderB/myFile 2>/dev/null

find / -path "folderA/folderB/myFile" 2>/dev/null
```

However, neither returns any results even though I know with certainty that the file exists.

So how can I search for a file using its containing folder structure?

Comment: Probably better off using `locate`, if it could be anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your examples `folderA/folderB/myFile` is matched against the entire path. You need a wildcard, something like:

```
find / -path "*/folderA/folderB/myFile"
```

Also note quoting is important. In general unquoted `*` triggers shell globbing ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690)).