# chown -R exclude some directory

Tags: linux, debian, file-permissions, chmod, chown

I want to exclude some large content directory

I'm Using it to chown Directory

```
chown -R admin /home/admin/web/public_html
```

is there anyway to exclude a subdirectory under html

Like:

```
chown -R admin exclude=/home/admin/web/public_html/content /home/admin/web/public_html
```

Something like that

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
chown -R admin $(ls -I content)
```

`ls -I` will list all except specified pattern.

Comment: **Warning: this answer is badly flawed.** Do not use it. Maybe unless you understand its flaws and can tell they won't do any harm in your particular case. But then it's still like using a gun as a hammer: not a wise idea, even if unloaded. The flaws: (1) [Parsing `ls` is wrong](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). (2) [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) (you have `chmod` instead of `for` but the problems are the same). (3) Possibly "[argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/108618)".

Answer (score 5):

In Linux the most general tool to do something to files meeting some criteria is `find`. Few other answers base on the `find … | xargs …` idea, which is robust only if it uses null-terminated strings. This means `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`, but these options are not required by POSIX.

With [POSIX `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) it's usually better to use `-exec` than to pipe to `xargs`. Personally I prefer `-exec` even if I can safely use `xargs`. Knowing that `-exec` is also a test, so it can be used to build custom tests ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1513652/432690)), it's good to be familiar with it anyway; and then there is no reason not to use it instead of `xargs`. The real power of `xargs` is its ability to parse strings with quotes and escaped characters; but this is hardly ever useful when reading from `find`, almost always it's harmful. Non-POSIX options like `-0` and `--no-run-if-empty` can make `xargs` a good companion of `find … -print0`, but still the good POSIX `-exec` is (almost?) always at least as good.

Your problem can be solved by

```
find /home/admin/web/public_html \
   -path /home/admin/web/public_html/content -prune \
   -o -exec chown admin {} +
```

It works like this: if the path is `…/content` then do not descend into it (`-prune`); otherwise (`-o`) execute `chown admin` on the file (note: [directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)).

Notes:

- Do not use `chown -R` here. The first file tested is `/home/admin/web/public_html` and if you use `chown -R` on it then nothing will be excluded.
- `-exec chown … {} +` can and will pass multiple paths to `chown`, while `-exec chown … {} \;` would pass just one (so there would be one `chown` spawned per file). The syntax with `+` reduces the number of spawned `chown` processes, this speeds things up. Even then `find` will spawn more than one `chown` process if the number of files is too large for a single command line (compare "[argument list too long](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128559/108618)"). Note it works because `chown` can take multiple paths; some tools cannot and for them the syntax with `+` is out of the question.
- `-path` matches against the entire path. The path is what `find` thinks the path is, not necessarily the canonical path. If the starting path is `/home/admin/web/public_html` then every path tested will start with this string; but if the starting path is `./` then every path tested will start with *this* string. In the former case `-path /home/admin/web/public_html/content` will never be true, even if `realpath ./` prints `/home/admin/web/public_html`, because the relevant directory will be identified by the string `./content` and this is the string you would want to match with `-path`. In general you need to adjust the argument of `-path` to the starting location(s) (or [use wildcards](https://superuser.com/a/1273086/432690) maybe).
- If you need to exclude multiple patterns then follow this example:

  ```
  find . \
     -path ./content -prune \
     -o -path ./foo/bar -prune \
     -o -path '*/baz' -prune \
     -o -exec chown admin {} +
  ```

  which can be compacted to

  ```
  find . \
     \( -path ./content \
        -o -path ./foo/bar \
        -o -path '*/baz' \
     \) -prune \
     -o -exec chown admin {} +
  ```

  where [parentheses are important](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690).

  With `-regex` you may be able to combine multiple patterns into one ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1488718/432690)). This test is not specified by POSIX though, implementations of `find` may or may not support it. You tagged [debian](/questions/tagged/debian); in Debian `find` is GNU `find`, it supports `-regex`.
- Other tests (e.g. `-name` or even `-exec`) can be used to exclude files.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude directories by using `!(enumeration_of_directories)` notation.
Example removing media and logs from `chown`

```
chown -R myuser:mygroup /www/myapp/!(media|logs)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. More information about this technique can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/889744/what-is-the-purpose-of-shopt-s-extglob

Comment: Using the `!(...)` syntax also requires the following shopt setting: `shopt -s extglob`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/889746/132098

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat unconventional approach: [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com/).

> Firejail is a SUID program that reduces the risk of security breaches by restricting the running environment of untrusted applications using Linux namespaces and seccomp-bpf. It allows a process and all its descendants to have their own private view of the globally shared kernel resources, such as the network stack, process table, mount table.

```
firejail --noprofile --quiet --blacklist=/home/admin/web/public_html/content chown -R admin /home/admin/web/public_html
```

It's a quite convenient generic way to protect some file(s). In this case, if `/home/admin/web/public_html/content` is a directory then `chown` will see an empty "impostor directory" instead. The tool will be able to act on it, so there will be no error. The real directory will stay unaffected.

There's a quirk: if `chown` is `/bin/chown` and you blacklist `/bin/chown` or `/bin` then `chown` will not run. In such case consider `--read-only` instead of `--blacklist`. See `man 1 firejail` for details.

From `sudo firejail … chown …` and `firejail … sudo chown …` I would prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d -not -path /home/admin/web/public_html  -prune -o -print0 | xargs -0 chown admin
```

Where `-type d` filter by directory and `-not -path /home/admin/web/public_html` exclude the directory.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I had try that just like this. `find . -type d \( -path contents -o -path admin/logs -o -path admin/data/backup -o -path admin/data/conversion -o -path admin/smarty/cache -o -path admin/data/engine/storage -o -path 78 -o -path 976 -o -path tmp \) -prune -o -print | xargs chown -R admin`

Comment: But Its also taking long time

Comment: Should I add `-not`

Comment: If you have a long list then a better approach is to create a file and grep the result.

So let say that the exclusion list is in the `zzNotNowChownPlease` file. Then:

`find . -type d |grep -fv zzNotNowChownPlease |xargs chown -R admin`

Should work. Just test the find+grep before.

Comment: The command is a no-op. The first object tested by `find .` is `.`. For it `-type d` is true, `-not -path …` is true, `-prune` is true, `-print0` is not evaluated. Nothing more is tested because of `-prune` for `.`. Thus the stdin of `xargs` is empty and the tool runs just `chown admin` which is invalid. Besides, in general if you start from `.` then each and every path tested by `find` will start with `./` or be exactly `.`; so I can tell in advance that `-path /home/admin/web/public_html` will *always* be false (in other words: `-path` does not perform `realpath` before testing).

Comment: can't find the "-o" in the man page

Answer (score -1):

for chown -R exclude subdirectory,but not the parent directory self

eg:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -path ./node_modules \) -prune -o -print0 |xargs -0 chown -R www-data:www-data
```

exclude . and chown subdirectories and files exclude 'node_modules' folder.

Comment: -1 How does this answer improve on what has already been posted in the past 3 years since this question was originally posted?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it works for the purpose : i want to chown recursively but exclude specific sub directory. 

mindepth 1 prevent the parent directory , which if included the -R option will cause chown for all subdirectories, so fail for exclude sub directory.

maxdepth 1 only first level sub directory and files for result, with -R option chown , it will exec exactly what we want.

-print0  ok for debug or dryrun

Comment: Well, happy this works for you. But this is not an answer that adds new insight that the other answers provide. Please remember this site is not a message board and just posting a “Me too!” answer with slight variation is not of real value to others.

Answer (score -2):

from /home/admin/web/public_html

```
find . ! -name "content" | xargs -I {} chown admin {}
```

should work fine, hope it helps you

Comment: Problems: (1) This will exclude every file named `content`, possibly somewhere deep in the directory tree, not only the specific directory in question. (2) This will still descend into the "excluded" directory and `chown` files in it. Usually "to exclude a directory" means "to exclude a directory along with its content". (3) `xargs` (even with `-I`) interprets quotes and backslashes. Newline characters, quotes and backslashes may appear in pathnames, they will cause the solution to fail.