# Combining multiple find commands into one

Tags: command-line, unix, find

I have a bash file with the following commands to copy books from my books folder into my toread / Read Later folder

```
find /books -name '*.pdf'  -exec cp -n {} /toread \;
find /books -name '*.epub'  -exec cp -n {} /toread \;
find /books -name '*.azw*'  -exec cp -n {} /toread \;
find /books -name '*.mobi'  -exec cp -n {} /toread \;
```

I want to get rid of the repetitiveness of these commands and batch the actions into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-o` in `find` expression is logical "or". There's a quirk though: juxtaposition (which is an implied "and" operator) takes precedence over the `-o` operator. For this reason you often need parentheses. They should be escaped or quoted, otherwise they will be interpreted by the shell:

```
find /books \( -name '*.pdf' -o -name '*.epub' -o -name '*.azw*' -o -name '*.mobi' ')' -exec cp -n {} /toread \;
```

Note I deliberately escaped the opening parenthesis and quoted the closing one, just to show the two ways.

Without parentheses the `-exec` part would apply only to `*.mobi` files (compare [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183879/108618)).