# open a random file in osx with command line

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, gnu, shuffle

I'd like to open a randomly selected file via the terminal.
I found `shuf`, which seems to be just the utility that I need, although I cannot figure out a way to make the command I'm working with recursive.

Initially I used `open $(ls | gshuf -n1)`, which works great if I have a flat directory structure.  How can I make this recurse into any number of subdirs and filter out files like `.DS_Store` and folders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Do not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).
- [Quote properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) (unless you know your shell fixes this, e.g. `zsh`).

The right tool is `find`. It works recursively, this solves your main problem. You can exclude various patterns if you know how.

Basic usage will be like:

```
open "$(find . -type f | shuf -n1)"
```

Newlines in filenames will break this. Your tools may or may not support non-POSIX options that allow to pass NUL-terminated data. This snippet works in my Debian:

```
find . -type f -print0 | shuf -z -n1
```

although if you embed it in `$(…)`, trailing newlines (if any) will still be removed.

To exclude names you can use syntax like `! -name .DS_Store`, but to exclude entire subdirectories you need [`-prune`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350090/108618). There are pitfalls:

- The order of operands matters, e.g. `-prune` for a directory should be before `-type f`, `-print`/`-print0` usually belongs at the end.
- Logical "or" (`-o`) [often requires parentheses](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690) and it's not as intuitive as you may wish.
- Omitting `-print`/`-print0` may give you more results than you expect. With complex logic it's good to explicitly include `-print`/`-print0`.

Study `man 1 find` to learn more. This is a working example that excludes two directories and two name patterns:

```
find . \( -name dir1 -o -name "dir 2" \) -prune -o -type f ! \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "echo*" \) -print
```

Since you need `$(…)` and I told you to quote properly, you should know that quotes inside `$(…)` are parsed separately. E.g. this is properly quoted:

```
open "$(find . -type f ! -name "not this file" | shuf -n1)"
```

(compare [this answer, quirk 2](https://superuser.com/a/1404245/432690)).

Comment: Works a treat - thank you!  I'm not aware of any newlines in any of my filenames, but that's an interesting edge case.