# using find in bash to operate of filles based on their extension patterns

Tags: bash, find

I am using "find" command to delete some useless filles of the given extensions from all subfolders located in the directory from which I am executing the command.

```
find -type f -name *.txt -delete
find -type f -name *.xml -delete
find -type f -name *.pdbqt -delete
find -type f -name *.txt -delete
```

is it possible to combine these 4 commands into the one to remove 4 types of filles via 1 command? Is it possible alternatively to use find in order to remove ALL filles which are NOT belong to the *.dlg extensions?

Comment: "not" is written with an exclamation mark. "or" is written as `-o`. To combine all that in one command: `find -type f \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.xml' -o ... \) -delete`. To delete everything but these files, `find -type f \( \! -name '*.txt' -a \! -name '*.xml' -a ... \) -delete`. Note that I put quotes around the wildcards. Since you delete files, ensure everything is backed up. Also run a test on a copy of this directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unquoted `*.txt` is bad. See [*`find` utility does not output all files when using wildcards*](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

> is it possible to combine these 4 commands into one?

Yes. See [*Combining multiple `find` commands into one*](https://superuser.com/q/1387979/432690).

```
find . \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.pdbqt' \) …
```

<sup>(This uses 3 patterns because your 4th command duplicates the 1st one and there is no point in using the same pattern twice.)</sup>

> Is it possible alternatively to use `find` in order to remove ALL files which are NOT belong to the `*.dlg` extensions?

Yes (and I assume you want regular files, not all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)):

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.dlg'        # -delete
```

If the above command prints files you really want to delete then run it with `#` removed.

The `! -name '*.dlg'` test is negated `-name '*.dlg'`. It succeeds if and only if `-name '*.dlg'` would fail.

You used `-delete` in the question, so your `find` apparently supports it. Users with less powerful `find` see [*`find`: `-exec rm {} \;` vs. `-delete` - why is the former widely recommended?*](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690)

Note in your case bare `find` works like `find .`. I used `find .` explicitly because some implementations of `find` require at least one path in the command line.