# How to delete any files that have not been used (access, change or modify) in X years

Tags: linux, bash, find, stat

i run this command

```
find BAR -type f -mtime +1095 # older than 3 years
```

and find this file:

```
BAR/foo.pdf
```

So i run this:

```
stat BAR/foo.pdf
Access: 2020-01-03 01:32:05.584393000 -0500
Modification: 2017-12-04 07: 59: 36.963225900 -0500
Change: 2020-01-02 10: 26: 28.907127100 -0500
# or
find BAR/foo.pdf -type f -printf "%p\n%a\n%c\n\n"
Fri Jan  3 01:32:05.5843930000 2020
Thu Jan  2 10:26:28.9071271000 2020
```

'Access' and 'Change' date is less than 3 years old

and if a run

```
find BAR -type f -ctime +1095 # older than 3 years
```

get nothing

What I want is to delete any files that have not been used (access or change or modify) in 3 years

PD: in the example, only 2 criteria are met. I would like my command to search for files that meet the 3 criteria: That has not been accessed, modified or changed for more than 3 years

Comment: I do not understand your question. I have modified my question for clarity

Comment: Are you asking how to use `-ctime` *and* `-mtime` within one `find` command? Or how to make `find` actually delete files?

Comment: I would like all 3 to match (access, change, modify) so that the search criteria is met, if this is possible

Comment: If you wanted files that match `-type f` *and* `-ctime +1095`, you would use `find BAR -type f -ctime +1095`. And you did. So you're already using two tests that must match simultaneously. What keeps you from adding *more* tests this way?

Comment: let me see if I understand. according to you can I do the following? `find BAR -type f -ctime +1095 -mtime +1095 -atime +1095`

Comment: Yes. Note if `find BAR -type f -ctime +1095` gives you nothing then adding more tests that must match will also give you nothing. In `BAR` there are no files that match the criteria. But in general this is how you add tests that must all match. In another directory there may be files that pass the tests.

Comment: So, just to be clear, could you answer the question and put, according to your criteria, what should be the correct command (with the correct order) to find any file that has not been used for more than 3 years. Thanks (to do the tests, and if it is correct select the answer as correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` combines tests using implicit `-a` (AND operator). In your command:

> ```
> find BAR -type f -ctime +1095
> ```

there are already two tests: `-type f` and `-mtime +1095`. The command may be written as:

```
find BAR -type f -a -ctime +1095
```

You can straightforwardly add more tests. Example:

```
find BAR -type f -ctime +1095 -mtime +1095 -atime +1095
# or with explicit -a
find BAR -type f -a -ctime +1095 -a -mtime +1095 -a -atime +1095
```

Each of the above two commands will print the pathname of a file if the file matches *all* the four tests (`-type f`, `-ctime +1095`, `-mtime +1095`, `-atime +1095`). It seems this is what you want (but note if `find BAR -type f -ctime +1095` gives you nothing then adding more tests that must match will also give you nothing; this is only because there are no regular files *in `BAR`* that match your criteria, in general the command may find something).

With (implicit or explicit) `-a`, if the test(s) before `-a` fails then the test(s) after `-a` will not be performed (because they cannot change the outcome). Some implementations of `find` change the order of tests for performance, trying hard not to break the logic.

There is also `-o` (OR operator). Its usage is sometimes non-intuitive because `-a` takes precedence (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1387985/432690)). And there is `!` to negate a test. In general you can combine multiple tests to build any(?) logic you want (see the "Theory" section of [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690)).

To actually delete files you need `-delete` or `-exec rm {} +` (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1222165/432690) to learn the difference).

Comment: It did not work for me in the tests carried out, but since it is a fairly accurate explanation, I select it, so as not to extend the question further. Keep investigating. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2465/17660):

> There are 3 kind of "timestamps":
>
> - Access - the last time the file was read
> - Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
> - Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

The man page of find says:

```
   -ctime n
          File's status was last changed less than, more than or
          exactly n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to
          understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file
          status change times.

   -mtime n
          File's data was last modified less than, more than or
          exactly n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to
          understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file
          modification times.
```

So mtime corresponds to Modify, while ctime corresponds to Change.

The results are correct according to the stat data:

```
Modification: 2017-12-04 07: 59: 36.963225900 -0500
Change: 2020-01-02 10: 26: 28.907127100 -0500
```

For access-time, you should use `atime`.

Comment: all 3 must match (access, change, modify) for the criteria to be met

Comment: You could use more than one condition in find, even all three, but ctime is not a very good criteria.

Comment: Could you explain why ctime is not a good criterion? Thanks. (I just restored the original data information. It was a problem of mine when editing the question. Sorry)

Comment: The meta data can be changed because of actions that happened to the parent folder, such as permissions change. This doesn't mean that the file itself has changed in any way. You risk finding all the files in the folder after such a change (or none).

Comment: let me try to summarize your argument. According to what you explain, for the criteria to match the command should be `find BAR -type f -mtime +1095 -atime +1095` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Well, joining these parameters does not work for me. anyway thanks