# Exclude subdirectory not working with grep command

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

This works for me, in that it excludes the "foo" directory from the root directory of the search:

```
grep -rn --exclude-dir=foo 'custom'
```

However this doesn't work:

```
grep -rn --exclude-dir=foo/bar 'custom'
```

But the "foo/bar" directory is still searched. I also tried it with quotes:

```
grep -rn --exclude-dir='foo/bar' 'custom'
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.

**Update**

Although not perfect, I used this workaround instead:

```
grep -rn 'custom'|grep -v 'foo/bar'
```

This will fail to find lines that contain both "foo/bar" and "custom".

Comment: In my Kubuntu `man 1 grep` says "skip any subdirectory whose *base* name matches". The base name of `foo` is `foo`, so it works; but the base name of `foo/bar` is `bar`. Can you exclude `bar`? or must it be `foo/bar`? (because you don't want to exclude other `bar`s).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I want to exclude bar which is a subdirectory of foo, my directory structure is foo/bar.

Comment: [`firejail --blacklist`](https://superuser.com/a/1575570/432690) is a general way to exclude any path, even if the tool you want to use doesn't support excluding.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski firejail sounds a bit complicated/convoluted. I found a workaround and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, solved it by calling

`grep -rn --exclude="**/foo/**" 'custom'`

Answer (score 0):

Use this operator `"*variable*"` as wildcard matching any directory you want to exclude from grep search.

In your case,

`grep -rn --exclude-dir={"*foo*"} 'custom'` will exclude directory or subdirectory with a name of 'foo'.

`grep -rn --exclude-dir={"*foo*","*bar*"} 'custom'` will exclude any directory and subdirectory with a name of 'foo' and 'bar'.