# shell helper function wrapping `find` and ignoring some dirs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have a bunch of scripts which follow the pattern of:

- find files which match a pattern
- do something

The problem is that there are several "hazard" directories which are large and slow, and should be avoided by pretty much every script.  Many of them do things like:

```
find_files() {
  find . -not \( \
      \( \
        -wholename './_output' \
        -o -wholename './release' \
        -o -wholename './target' \
        -o -wholename '*/third_party/*' \
        -o -wholename '*/vendor/*' \
      \) -prune \
    \)
}
```

The first problem I have is that every script embeds the list of hazards, but they have diverged over time.  I thought I would write a helper function which feels like find, but includes some overrides.

So now the second problem:  Some of them need to parameterize the paths, so:

```
find_files() {
  find "$@" -not \( \
```

Some of them need to parameterize the expression by sticking "$@" at the end.

Because of how find works, no script can parameterize BOTH the paths AND the expression -- paths must precede expression, but expression evaluation is more complicated and I can't figure how to add filters at the end.

Is there some technique in find that I just cant figure out (I admit that find's behavior is weird to me) which would let me write something like:

```
my_find() {
    # some find expression which takes "$@" as valid args to find
    # and ignores all the hazard directories
}

my_find . -type f -name '*.foobar' -print0
```

?

Comment: Consider `firejail` (compare: [*`chown -R` exclude some directory*](https://superuser.com/a/1575570/432690)). This will also allow you to keep the list of hazards in one place as a profile.

Comment: Why not `locate` from `mlocate` ? It set a cron job daily in the background, and a call to `locate` is very quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will convert each argument being exactly `-exclude_hazards` to arguments responsible for the desired exclusions:

```sh
my_find () (
#!/bin/sh
mark=
for arg do
  [ -z "$mark" ] && { set --; mark=y; }
  case "$arg" in
    -exclude_hazards )
      set -- "$@" \
! \( \
  \( \
        -path './_output' \
     -o -path './release' \
     -o -path './target' \
     -o -path '*/third_party/*' \
     -o -path '*/vendor/*' \
  \) -prune \
  \)
    ;;
    * )
      set -- "$@" "$arg"
    ;;
  esac
done
exec find "$@"
)
```

Usage:

```
my_find . -exclude_hazards -type f -name '*.foobar' -print0
```

This is not exactly what you wanted, but the implementation is simple, without any need for knowing the meaning of other arguments. In other words the function does not have to parse other arguments and classify them as options/paths/expression in order to inject extra code*. You explicitly put `-exclude_hazards` in the right place and there is no ambiguity, no guessing, no dependency on some particular implementation of `find`. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Note `my_find . -exclude_hazards -exec echo -exclude_hazards \;` will convert both occurrences of `-exclude_hazards`. I could make the function convert only the first occurrence, but since I don't expect this quirk to be a problem in practice, I decided not to complicate the code. Besides, the fixed function would still misbehave for `my_find . -exec echo -exclude_hazards \;`. In my opinion this is a reasonable price for KISS.

Notes:

- The shell code is portable.
- I wanted the solution to work with virtually any implementation of `find`, therefore

  - I changed your non-portable `-not` to equivalent portable `!`;
  - I changed your non-portable `-wholename` to equivalent portable `-path`.
- What looks like a shebang is just a comment, it will be ignored when the function gets created. I put it there, so you can copy the whole body of the function, paste into a regular file and make the file a standalone script; the line will become a shebang then, possibly no adjustment will be required.

---

* Classifying arguments as options/paths/expression is possible only if you know exactly what your `find` is. Consider this:

1. In an invocation of `find`, first there may be options, arguments starting with `-`. Portable options are `-H` and `-L`. Implementations may introduce other options.
2. Then there are paths. Some implementations of `find` work well when the number of paths is zero (e.g. GNU `find` uses `.` as the default).
3. Finally an argument (if any) that starts with a `-`, or is a `!` or a `(` is the beginning of an expression made up of primaries and operators. There may be no such argument, the expression may be empty. Implementations may support non-portable primaries and/or operators.

This means `find -X …` may be a valid command that works with some (future, custom) implementation of `find`, but we cannot know in advance if `-X` is an option or the beginning of an expression. There is no way to tell, unless you know how this `find` will treat it. Our simple function does not try to guess, it's the user who should know and use either `my_find -X -exclude_hazards …` (`-X` is an option) or `my_find -exclude_hazards -X …` (`-X` was the beginning of the expression).