# Find and sort numerical filenames

Tags: linux, sorting, filenames

I am trying to find files that match `time=*` and then need to display it by sorting it numerically.
The result file names would be  :

```
first/path/time=001.jpg
first/path/time=002.jpg
second/path/time=001.jpg
...
```

which I want to see as,

```
first/path/time=001.jpg
second/path/time=001.jpg
first/path/time=002.jpg
...
```

sorted numerically with respect to the 3 digits on file name.

For now, i tried 
`find . -name time=* | rev | sort | rev`

which does work for single digits but with numbers like `019` `021` it does not work.

Full path would be something like,

```
path/to/folder1/alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/time=001.jpg
path/to/folder1/alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/time=001.jpg
path/to/folder2/alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/time=001.jpg
.
.
.
```

I think it would be easiest if the files could be sorted using only last 7 characters. `001.jpg` `010.jpg`... however sadly `sort` does not support support negative indexing to get last 6 characters :(

Comment: (1) What OS? Looks like some Unix, still you should make it clear. (2) Quote the pattern, [or else](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690)...

Comment: hey, Its Linux and what do you mean by quote the pattern?

Comment: I mean exactly what my answer says under [this link I have already gave you](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

Comment: hi thanks, but that was not the problem with me. I dont have `time=*` file in current directory to have that problem. But definitely a new thing to learn! thanks again! i will keep this in find for future.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski oh no. i just meant `time=001.jpg` `time=002.jpg` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
find . -name 'time=*' | sort -t= -k3
```

But this is a more safe sorting, as per Kamil Maciorowski's comment:

```
perl -C -F= -wnle 'push @a,[$_,split(/\./,$F[-1])]; END {$,="\n"; print map{$$_[0]} sort{$$a[1]<=>$$b[1]} @a}'
```

Use it in the pipeline afer `find` instead of `sort` in the first one.

Comment: Unless you encounter `third/path/a=foo/bar/...`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `I am trying to find files that match time=*` says the question.

Comment: Add `third/path/a=foo/bar/time=001.jpg` to the set provided by the OP. It will end up after `first/path/time=002.jpg` because of the extra `=`. Your answer may or may not be sufficient for the OP, it's good to know its limitations. Maybe the other answer is flawed as well; I don't know `ruby` enough to tell.

Comment: hi @tomasz, thanks for your reply but as @Kamil says it actually does not work for me as my actual path is something like `first/path/parameter=1/time=001.jpg` `first/path/parameter=0.1/time=001.jpg` `second/path/parameter=1/time=001.jpg`   ...
:(

Comment: @hadik If that's regular and as you present, then change `-k2` to `-k3`.

Comment: @tomasz cool solution this actually worked. nice combination of -t and -k, I do have regular names, so this is perfect thanks ! :)

Comment: Hah, did not know that option of `sort`. +1

Comment: @hadik Welcome. I added Perl too for the weird cases.

Answer (score 1):

A quickie with left-overs I picked from the command line :-)

```
find . -name time="*" -exec ruby -e "s='{}'; puts s.split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]+s" \; |
sort -n | colrm 1 3
```

**Explanation:**

My friend Ruby stores the path string given by find as `{}` and stores it into a variable `s`. Then she splits the string along `=` characters and keeps the last part (index -1 in the result array), e.g. `002.jpg`. 
Then she splits this string on `.` characters and keeps the first part (index 0 in the result array), assuming the files are named `ddd.<ext>`, which results is the three digit number part, e.g. `002`.

Finally she prints this and adds the original path string. This would give:

```
002./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/path/time=002.jpg
001./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/path/time=001.jpg
021./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=021.jpg
001./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=001.jpg
019./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=019.jpg
```

The additional pipe commands sort the output numerically (`sort -n`) and finally remove the first three columns of the output (`colrm 1 3`).

**Example:**

```
test$ find . -name time="*" -exec ruby -e "s='{}'; puts s.split('=')[-1].split('.')[0]+s" \; 
| sort -n | colrm 1 3
./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=001.jpg
./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/path/time=001.jpg
./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/path/time=002.jpg
./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=019.jpg
./alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=0.1/path/time=021.jpg
```

Comment: this one has the same problem as the other solution suggested by @tomasz . as my path contains multiple `=` this sorts through the numbers after first `=` and then the second `=` and so on. So my files are actually not sorted as i like.

Comment: OK, can I assume the last "="? (Note that I updated the index from "1" to "-1")

Comment: @hadik Note that you added that requirement about multiple "=" after I posted my first version.

Comment: It looks like Ruby's called for each file found.

Comment: Yes, this was a quick hack. It is not optimized.

Comment: @mvw thanks for the reply. this works now but solution by tomasz was easiest for my problem :)

Comment: At least I had `f1rst p0st` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no path is insane enough to require `find ... -print0`:

```
find . -type f -name "time=*" | awk -F '=' '{ print $NF "=" $0 }' | sort -n | cut -d "=" -f 2-
```

I used `awk` to extract parts behind the last `=`, it outputs full lines with *additional* relevant part in front, separating by *additional* `=`. E.g.:

```
001.jpg=path/to/folder1/alpha=0.1_beta=0.2_gamma=1.0/time=001.jpg
```

These are sorted numerically with `sort`. Then `cut` extracts parts after this additional (first) `=`; these are the original paths.

There are exactly four processes created: `find`, `awk`, `sort`, `cut`. Alternatives that use the syntax of `find ... -exec some_tool ... \;` create one `some_tool` process per matching file.

Comment: i didnt know about `awk`, thanks for suggestions :)