# How to handle spaces in directory names using grep

Tags: grep, sorting

I have a directory tree where some of the directories have spaces in the names:

```
top
|-- subdir 1
    |-- subdir a
        |-- file1.csv
        |-- file2.csv
    |-- subdir b
        |-- file1.csv
    |-- subdir c
        |-- file3.csv
```

I want to write a `grep` command to recursively find text in the directory structure, but the output has to be sorted according to the timestamp of the files. The closes I've gotten is this:

```
find . -name *.csv | sort | xargs grep "some text" -0
```

The problem is that the spaces are throwing off `grep` and you get results like

> grep: ./subdir: No such file or directory 
>   grep: 1: No such file or directory

It's interpreting `subdir 1` as two separate directories, `subdir` and `1`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these spaces are the problem. If the tools you use can work with null-terminated strings, this is the way:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 grep "some text"
```

This approach should also work in your case:

```
find . -name "*.csv" | sort | xargs -I {} grep "some text" {}
```

Notes:

- I don't know how this `sort` makes "the output sorted according to the timestamp of the files". I'm just debugging your command.
- You need to quote `*.csv` like I did to avoid [this scenario](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).