# What are all of the globs I can use with grep in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, bash-scripting, wildcards, globbing

Linux and Unix-like shells like `bash` allow for the use of globs to approximate filenames and make file searching easier. I'm aware of the wildcard glob (*). What other globs exist in `bash` that I can make use of with `grep`?

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions; these are different than globs. Some `grep` implementations use globs with options like `--exclude=GLOB` but I think these options are not required by POSIX. So you shouldn't assume `grep` knows anything about globs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I'm aware of the difference between globs and regex, but I was under the impression that GNU grep supports globs by default (even with `grep -F`) just like most other commands in `bash`.

Comment: "just like most other commands in `bash`" – `grep` is not a "command in `bash`" but a separate executable that you can run without a shell, if you know how. You should carefully distinguish globs expanded by `bash` before `grep` (or any command invoked in a shell) even runs from globs, regular expressions or anything alike that is supported by the command itself.

Comment: E.g. `find . -name` supports glob-like pattern matching. [See what happens](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690) when you let the shell expand them.

Comment: So you're saying that `grep` itself doesn't use globs, and so globs can't be used with it? Something like `grep -f *.txt` won't return text files, or `grep Match* file.txt` won't return Match1, Match2, Match3, etc?

Comment: The shell will expand globs before passing them to `grep` in the argument list. Thus, `grep -f *.txt` will expand to something like `grep -f file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`, and `grep` will interpret `file1.txt` as the file to read search patterns from, and `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` as files to search for those patterns. `grep` has no idea whatsoever that there was a glob pattern involved, it only knows that it got the strings "-f", "file1.txt", "file2.txt", and "file3.txt" as arguments.

Comment: Invoke `set -x` (use `set +x` to revert this later). Then run `grep -f *.txt 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` (redirections are just to make the command itself silent). Whatever you see after `+` is the actual command. Try it in directories with 0, 1 or more matching files. You will see what arguments `grep` really gets.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the bash builtin parameter expansion called glob, and what grep can understand as a search input.

Typical glob use is the `*`, to expand to any string in it's place that matches the rest of the string. For example:

```bash
ls
# 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
grep "search string" *.txt
# expands the star to match anything ending in .txt, so in this case is the same as:
grep "search string" 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

This is all bash, and also works with `echo` for example (but since it's bash it doesn't work inside quotes).
To your actual question, [here is the glob manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) which also describes several other matchers you can use as a glob. To summarize (using `ls` for the sake of simplicity):

```
ls ?.txt # matches any single character
ls [0-9].txt # matches a single character from 0 to 9
ls [[:digit:]].txt # same as above
ls [0-9A-Za-z].txt # matches any alphanumeric character
```

See the manpage for a complete list plus some notable special cases like matching a `.` for example.

For there grep search string there are several forms of (semi)standard regex strings you can use, see for example `-e`, `-E` or `-P` in the man page and general regex help online for the supported syntaxes that are way to numerous to list here.