# Extract .tar.gz files in different subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, tar

i have phenological data of different tree species, but they are saved by the bigger Treegroup.

The output of `find . -name *.tar.gz`is:

```
./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_070.tar.gz
./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_071.tar.gz
./Fagus/PEP725_DE_108_010.tar.gz
./Acer/PEP725_DE_115_000.tar.gz
./Acer/PEP725_DE_115_030.tar.gz
./Betula/PEP725_DE_106_020.tar.gz
```

I want to extract every file in their subdirectory and the name of the output directory should be the same as the tar-file.

I manage to extract all with `find . -name *.tar.gz -execdir tar -xvzf "{}" \;` But this does not create a directory name after the zipped files.

How do i do this? `-C` needs the directory already to be existend...

So in the end i would like to have

```
Tilia/EP725_DE_129_070/content_of_PEP725_DE_129_070.tar.gz
```

and so on...

Comment: Note: quote properly, `-name "*.tar.gz"`. Compare [`find` utility does not output all files when using wildcards](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690). You may get away few times but it will hit you eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `tar` supports `--one-top-level` option:

```
find . -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir tar --one-top-level -xvzf {} \;
```

From [`man 1 tar`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html):

> `--one-top-level[=DIR]`
>
> Extract all files into `DIR`, or, if used without argument, into a subdirectory named by the base name of the archive (minus standard compression suffixes recognizable by `--auto-compress`).

Note: `{}` may or may not be quoted but `*.tar.gz` *should* be quoted to avoid mishaps like this: [`find` utility does not output all files when using wildcards](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

---

If your `tar` doesn't support `--one-top-level` option then `-C` is quite a good idea, you just need to create a respective directory first. This command, however, goes a step further and doesn't even use `-C`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -execdir sh -c '
   dirn="${1%.tar.gz}"         # desired directory name
   mkdir -- "$dirn"            # creating a directory
   cd -- "$dirn" &&
   tar -xvzf ../"$1"           # extracting to it
' find-sh {} \;
```

The only non-POSIX component here is… the `tar` itself. `tar` is [only recognized as a legacy tool](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) without gzip support. In POSIX (since 2001), the equivalent of `tar` is the [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) program, also without gzip support. As far as I know there is no `gzip` (nor equivalent) in POSIX, so it's impossible to create a solution fully compliant with the formal POSIX standard.

Fortunately `gzip` is a *de facto* standard. In the worst case the above piece of code should run `gzip` before `tar` (or `pax`).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What does POSIX mean?

Comment: @m4D_guY [Portable Operating System Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). A solution that is fully POSIX-compliant will work on variety of systems. In general there are many tools (or options) only supported on "large" Linuxes. If you can use them, great! But if you work with an embedded "minimal" Unix, or on Mac (where tools often differ from these of Linux) etc. then a solution that doesn't go beyond POSIX may be a lifesaver.

Comment: To be honest i dont know how this works... i always only click the up button not the "check" button, where is the difference, a link is totally fine

Comment: @m4D_guY Please take our [tour] then. You need 15 reputation to vote up; there is no such restriction for accepting an answer to any of your questions. If you got a good answer to your other question (not necessarily on Super User, Stack Overflow maybe?), consider accepting it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for f in $(find . -name *.tar.gz); 
do 
    cd $(dirname $d)       # to ./Tilia/
    d=$(basename $f .tar.gz)  
    mkdir $d               # ./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_070
    cd $d                  # To ./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_070
    tar -xvzf ../$d.tar.gz # extracting ./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_070.tar.gz in ./Tilia/PEP725_DE_129_070
    cd ../..               # back to top
done
```

Untested, use at your own risk.

Copy above to a file and `source` the file.

If you feel adventurous, you can also make that a one-liner.

Comment: Until wild cherry (or another name with space in it) pops up…