# How to suppress certain error message in 'find' command?

Tags: ubuntu, find

`find /var/log/myfile.*.txt -type f`

If no file is present matching that pattern, I'm getting error logs like `No such file or directory`.

Question: how can I prevent only this error message?
I could of course add a `2>/dev/null` at the end, but that would suppress any errors. How could I just ignore the one mentioned?

Because I have a cronjob that deletes some files periodically, and always logs errors if no file was present:

`@daily find /var/log/myfile.*.txt -mtime +7 -delete`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right thing in this case is not to trigger this message at all.

When you run this in a shell

> ```
> find /var/log/myfile.*.txt -type f
> ```

`/var/log/myfile.*.txt` is expanded by the shell; `find` gets expanded object(s) or literal `/var/log/myfile.*.txt` if there is no match. The latter case triggers `No such file or directory`.

You can create a dummy file first: `touch '/var/log/myfile.dummy_name.txt'` (compare [elephant in Cairo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_Cairo)). This "solution" is not really elegant though.

A better solution is to make `find` handle the pattern:

```
find /var/log/ -type f -name "myfile.*.txt"
```

where double-quotes prevent globbing in the shell (compare [this](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690)). In this case `*` is handled by the `find` itself because `-name` supports such patterns.

The above approach however can match `myfile.*.txt` in *any subdirectory* of `/var/log/` as well. If your `find` supports `-maxdepth`, use it:

```
find /var/log/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "myfile.*.txt"
```

If not, see this: [*Limit POSIX find to specific depth?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618)

---

Your OS probably already uses `logrotate(8)` to manage logfiles.

In my Debian `logrotate` runs daily because of `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`; it should be similar in Ubuntu. I can create a custom config in `/etc/logrotate.d/` and manage arbitrary logfiles this way. Consider this approach.

Comment: While you gave an answer similar to the one I would have given. I'd like to remind you that the OP asked how to **suppress certain error message** (I want you to get full credit for the answer). :)

Comment: @somebody Yeah, the (somewhat) Asperger's part of my mind strongly agrees. On the other hand the question body does ask how to prevent. In addition I think suppression would not be the Right Thing here.

Comment: Maybe you're right. It was a good answer, and I didn't want to see it disqualified on a *technicality*. That's all. I'm voting for your answer. :)