# SSH into remote machine, run find command, then rsync the results of the find back to the local machine?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync

Basically the title.

Here is what I have had success with so far:

A) this successfully finds the file I need and displays it in the terminal of my local machine:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotemachine find /home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/ -type f -name 'examplefile*' | xargs echo
```

B) this successfully rsyncs the needed file from the remote machine to my local machine:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress remoteuser@remotemachine:/home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz /home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory
```

These two commands work fine when I am there to interact with it; i.e. i can see the output of the find and then manually run the second command, but what I am struggling with is tying these two concepts together as a single command so it can be run all at once (so it can be automated via a cronjob). In other words, I need to ssh into the remote machine, find the needed file, and rysync the results of the find back to my local machine, all in one go.

I have private-key no-password ssh access from my local machine into the remote machine. I do not have private-key no-password ssh access from the remote machine into my local machine, but probably could set it up if necessary. I am wondering if there is a way to do this entirely from the local machine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Finding files

> this successfully finds the file

No. Your first command only *luckily* finds the file. There are few problems with it. You were lucky it gave you a useful output.

In your manual approach `| xargs echo` is almost a no-op. Almost, because it may introduce ambiguity. This may not be a problem if there is just one match and its name is not troublesome in this context. I won't explain what "troublesome in this context" means because even if `| xargs echo` was completely fine, your original first command would still work without it anyway.

Your `ssh` command is somewhat flawed on its own. This is your command without the unneeded `xargs`:

> ```
> ssh remoteuser@remotemachine find /home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/ -type f -name 'examplefile*'
> ```

It's good `examplefile*` is quoted but it's not enough. The quotes prevent the local shell from globbing. Then `ssh` recognizes the first operand that looks like a command to run on the remote side and builds an acutal command from it *and* every operand that follows. In your case these operands are `find`, `/home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/`, `-type`, `f`, `-name` and `examplefile*`. The last one is *without* quotes because the quotes was "used" by the local shell. In effect the remote command built by `ssh` and run by a shell on the remote side is

```
find /home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/ -type f -name examplefile*
```

and this does trigger globbing on the remote side. In some circumstances this may give you an error or unexpected results (see [this](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/432690)).

One interesting scenario. If `examplefile*` is expanded by globbing on the remote side to `examplefile123.tar.gz` (because such file happens to be in the current working directory and it's the only match), the `-name` primary will get this exact string, not the pattern you typed, and the whole search will be limited to this exact filename. The command I present below is not flawed like this, `-name` gets the pattern for sure. Depending on what files there are on the remote side, it may be my command will find more files than yours.

This is the right command:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotemachine 'find /home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/ -type f -name "examplefile*"'
```

Single-quotes embrace the entire code destined to the remote side. Double-quotes will survive and prevent globbing on the remote side.

You can store the result in a file on the local side like this:

```
ssh remoteuser@remotemachine 'find /home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/ -type f -name "examplefile*"' > filelist
```

---

#### Passing result to `rsync`

There is this question: [*How to `rsync` only a specific list of files?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16647476/10765659) The best answer advises `--files-from`. This is what `man 1 rsync` says:

> `--files-from=FILE`
>   Using this option allows you to specify the exact list of files to transfer (as read from the specified `FILE` or `-` for standard input). […]

Please read the entire relevant fragment of the manual, especially what it says about implied `-R`:

> The `--relative` (`-R`) option is implied, which preserves the path information that is specified for each item in the file (use `--no-relative` or `--no-R` if you want to turn that off).

After you run the last command provided above, you will have `filelist` to use with `--files-from`. An example command:

```
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress --files-from=filelist --no-relative remoteuser@remotemachine:/ /home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory
```

On the local side paths will be like

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

Without `--no-relative` you would get (on the local side) paths like

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/home/remoteuser/exampledirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

Note I used `/` as the source (remote) path. This is because you gave an absolute path to `find`, so all paths in `filelist` are absolute; but `rsync` will treat them relative to the directory you specify. Therefore the tool should start in (remote) `/` to get to the right objects.

But if you used `find ./exampledirectory/ …` then `rsync` should be given `remoteuser@remotemachine:.` (or just `remoteuser@remotemachine:`) because all paths in `filelist` would be relative to `remoteuser`'s home directory. In such case without `--no-relative` the local path would be created like

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/exampledirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

And if the remote command was

```
cd exampledirectory && find . …
```

then all paths in `filelist` would be relative to `remoteuser`'s `~/exampledirectory`. `rsync` should use `remoteuser@remotemachine:exampledirectory`. Without `--no-relative` the local path would be

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

which looks like the one where `--no-relative` was used. The option still makes a difference for subdirectories. If the (remote) file was `…/exampledirectory/foo/examplefile123.tar.gz` then you would get

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

or

```
/home/localuser/examplelocaldirectory/foo/examplefile123.tar.gz
```

depending on whether or not you used `--no-relative`.

---

#### Hints and improvements

- `--files-from=-` will make `rsync` read its stdin. You want a single command, so this will be very useful:

  ```
  ssh … 'find …' | rsync … --files-from=- …
  ```
- You were talking about "the needed file", one file; but in general you may get multiple paths from `find`. `rsync` will have no problem in processing them all. There are few ways to limit what you get:

  1. More restrictive `find`. E.g. `find … -print -quit` (if `-quit` is supported) to get just one result (but it may not be the one you expect).
  2. Filtering on the remote side. E.g. `ssh … 'find … | sort -R | head -n 1'` to get just one result, randomly chosen.
  3. Filtering on the local side. E.g. `ssh … 'find …' | sort -R | head -n 1`.

  In general filtering on the remote side will reduce the amount of data your `ssh` pulls. But if the remote machine is slow/limited and the filter stresses the CPU or requires lot of memory, you may want to pull more data and parse it on the local side.
- In Linux filenames can contain newline characters. If this happens in your case then a single path will look like multiple entries in the list. `rsync` will try to retrieve nonexistent (or wrong) files (or existing directories!). If `find` on the remote side supports `-print0` (it may or may not), use it as the final action, along with `-0` option of `rsync`. The entries will be null-terminated. The commands will look like this:

  ```
  ssh … 'find … -print0' > filelist
  rsync -0 …
  ```

  Note if you want to process/filter the list before passing to `rsync`, all tools you use must treat null characters as delimiters.

You can combine these hints. Example:

```
ssh … 'find … -print0 | head -z -n 1' | rsync -0 … --files-from=- …
```