# cannot escape space in scp command in a while loop

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, vmware, scp

I'm trying to build a script to make a mirror-backup of a free ESXi 6.5 to another free ESXi 6.5 host. I'm almost there but this issue is driving me crazy. This is a part of the script; I am using Bash for the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' ! -name *-flat.vmdk | while read line; do
    dir1=$(dirname "${line}"| sed 's/ /\\ /g')
    dir2=$(dirname "${line}"| sed 's/ /\\\\ /g')
    ssh -n root@XX.XX.XX.XX "mkdir -p $dir1"
    cmd=$(echo $line "XX.XX.XX.XX:\""$dir2"/\"")
    echo $cmd
    scp -pr $cmd
done
```

output is:

- for every VM that have no spaces in name, succeded.
- for every VM with spaces in name, (last word in VM name):  No such file or directory

I tried everything to make this SCP get the full path and it ignores everything: Put single quotes, double quotes, escape char to space, double, triple escape chars. Put args directly in SCP, put all the args of SCP in a variable and pass it after.

When running outside script, command runs flawless. When running in script, it's giving error and takes only last part after space.

Comment: I created 2 vars (dir1 and dir2) because when creating remote dirs, dir1 works good, but when copying with scp i read [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/joshis/scp-and-path-with-spaces-another-waste-of-time-issue) that i need to double-escape or triple-escape the spaces

Comment: I have a hunch that you should use array...

Comment: How would that save me from "space nightmare" ? I would still have to pass the variable to scp....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is flawed in many aspects.

`-name *-flat.vmdk` is prone to [globbing](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690); what it expands to depends on files in the current working directory. `*` should be quoted (e.g. `-name '*-flat.vmdk'`).

This is not the only time your code lacks quotes. `echo $line` is flawed because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618) (and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618) in general).

`read line` should be at least `IFS= read -r line`. It would still fail if any path (returned by `find`) contained the newline character (which is a valid character in file names). For this reason `find … -exec … \;` is better. You can go like this:

```
find … -exec sh -c '…' sh {} \;
```

which introduces another level of quoting; or like this:

```
find … -exec helper_script {} \;
```

which makes quoting in the `helper_script` easier. The latter approach is advocated by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1485403/432690), still the answer doesn't fix other issues.

Your variables `dir1` and `dir2` seem to inject some cumbersome escaping to deal with spaces. You should not rely on escaping like this. Even if you managed to make it work with spaces, there are other characters you would need to escape in general. The right way is to *quote* properly.

There are at least three levels of quoting:

1. in the original shell where `find` is invoked;
2. in a shell spawned by `-exec sh` or in a shell interpreting the `helper_script`;
3. in a shell spawned on the remote side by `ssh … "whatever command"` (similarly for paths processed by `scp`).

Introducing a `helper_script` makes the first level not interfere with the rest. The main command would be:

```
find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' ! -name '*-flat.vmdk' -exec /path/to/helper_script {} \;
```

And the `helper_script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# no need for bash

addrs=XX.XX.XX.XX

pth="$1"
drctry="${pth%/*}"
# no need for dirname (separate executable)

ssh "root@$addrs" "mkdir -p '$drctry'"
scp -pr "$pth" "$addrs:'$drctry/'"
```

Now the important thing is `ssh` gets `mkdir -p 'whatever/the var{a,b}e/expand$t*'` as a string. This is passed to the remote shell and *interpreted*. Without the inner single quotes it could be interpreted in a way you don't want; my example exaggerates this. You could try to escape every troublesome character, it would be hard; so quote.

*But* if the variable contains any single-quote then some substring can be unquoted on the remote side. This opens a code injection vulnerability. E.g. this path:

```
…/foo/'$(nasty command)'bar/baz/…
```

will be very dangerous when embedded in single-quotes and interpreted. You should sanitize `$drctry` beforehand:

```
drctry="$(printf '%s' "${pth%/*}" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g")"
```

The example dangerous path will now look like this:

```
…/foo/'"'"'$(nasty command)'"'"'bar/baz/…
```

This is somewhat similar to your usage of `sed`, but since the single-quote character is now the only troublesome character, it should be better.

`scp` needs similar quoting in the remote path for basically the same reason. Again, proper escaping with backslashes is more hassle (if possible at all).

---

A slight improvement is to allow the helper script to process more than one object. This will run less shell processes:

```
find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' ! -name '*-flat.vmdk' -exec /path/to/helper_script_2 {} +
```

And the `helper_script_2`:

```
#!/bin/sh

addrs=XX.XX.XX.XX

for pth; do
   drctry="$(printf '%s' "${pth%/*}" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g")"
   ssh "root@$addrs" "mkdir -p '$drctry'"
   scp -pr "$pth" "$addrs:'$drctry/'"
done
```

---

It's possible to build a standalone command (not referring to any helper script) with `-exec sh -c '…'` (or `-exec sh -c "…"`). Because of the most outer quotes, this would tun into a quoting and/or escaping frenzy. The following trick with command substitution and here document is useful to avoid this:

```
find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ \
   -type f \
   -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' \
 ! -name '*-flat.vmdk' \
   -exec sh -c "$(cat << 'EOF'

addrs=XX.XX.XX.XX

for pth; do
   drctry="$(printf '%s' "${pth%/*}" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g")"
   ssh "root@$addrs" "mkdir -p '$drctry'" \
   && scp -pr "$pth" "$addrs:'$drctry/'"
done

EOF
   )" sh {} +
```

To fully understand this (and some fragments in previous snippets) in the context of variable expansion you need to know about [quotes within quotes](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690) and [why `EOF` is quoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379581/108618) (the linked answer cites `man bash` but this is more general [POSIX behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04)). Also note I added `-type f` to rule out possible directories matching the regex; and I wrote `ssh … && scp …`, so if the former fails (which includes when `mkdir -p` fails), the latter will not run.

Comment: THANX a LOT ! Your advices and info are VERY precious ! Some of them i know (like why i need and what it is EOF, some cases of why i need to quote). I'm not a heavy scripting user, i don't do this often, i usualy build scripts to automate tasks and focus on get the job done and use as low resurces as i can (exclude redundant steps, data). I use a lot of forums but this forum by far gave me most of the answers i needed. This is the first time in ~10 years i neded help to make a script working.. I'm getting old... :(

Comment: my (almost) final script looks like that (the testing is still pending as i cannot simulate the copying of the disks without snapshot of VM, and i cannot skip first VMs that works anyway):

Comment: #!/bin/sh

echo "--------- Backup config files -------------"

find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ \
   -type f \
   -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' \
 ! -name '*-flat.vmdk' \
   -exec sh -c "$(cat << 'EOF'
addrs=XX.XX.XX.XX
for pth; do
   drctry="$(printf '%s' "${pth%/*}" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g")"
   ssh "root@$addrs" "mkdir -p '$drctry'" && scp -pr "$pth" "$addrs:'$drctry/'"
done
EOF
   )" sh {} +```

Comment: ```echo "----------- Backup VM disks ---------------"
vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | sed -e '1d' -e 's/ \[.*$//' | while read -r line; do 
 vmid="$(echo $line | awk '{print $1;}')"
 vname="$(echo $line | awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')"
 vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.create $vmid backup 'Snapshot created by Backup Script' 0 0
 scp -pr "/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/$vname/$vname-flat.vmdk" XX.XX.XX.XX:"/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/$vname"
 vim-cmd vmsvc/snapshot.removeall $vmid
done```

Comment: it doesn't work. same issue. I'm trying to use printf instead of echo, like in your example. How can i assign the first word to a variable (it's a number) and the rest to another variable (it's the VM name, that may contain spaces) so that i could build the path for scp later ?

Comment: @Costin Comments are not for posting code. Please make an edit to the question, add the current script (without removing the original content all the answers refer to), explain what improvements you made so far and what the outcome is. If you can identify the *exact* path that makes the script fail, include it in the question as well.

Comment: @Costin One more thing. This is a Q&A site. If you believe your original problem is not solved yet, remove the acceptance from my answer to indicate the problem stands.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies:
1) you code works flawles. That's why i marked as answer.
2) it's my first time posting in this site, so i don't know a lot of things about rules and limitations. I will edit my post in order to paste the code.
3) i didn't make myself well understood: when i said that "it doesn't work" i refered to my whole script, not your part. And i came with another question regarding usage of printf. If you could help, I'll be more than greateful. (i already am, but just saying :) )

Comment: @Costin OK. If the old problem is resolved, do not edit the question. To solve a separate problem ask a new question. Link to this one if it provides context.

Answer (score 0):

Move the stuff on the right of the pipe (`|`) to a shell script, then do something like

```
find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' ! -name *-flat.vmdk -exec /path/to/shell/script {} \;
```

The `{}` will properly escape each and every file name it successfully `find`s and then call your script passing the escaped/quoted file name as the first argument.  Simply access it with `$1` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Witness the magic of array:

```
$ line="meh bleh"
$ dir="hello\ world"
$ cmd=$(echo "$line" "$dir")
$ for i in $cmd; do echo "$i"; done
meh
bleh
hello\
world
$ for i in "$cmd"; do echo "$i"; done
meh bleh hello\ world
$ cmd=("$line" "$dir")
$ for i in "${cmd[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
meh bleh
hello\ world
$
```

The problem with putting everything in a simple variable is that no one can tell what each argument is anymore.

Comment: thank you, i'll use arrays. I'll post the final version here when it will be done. :)

Comment: If you are not using bash, array may not be available btw. Actually I'm not sure you need it anyway. I don't see why you would need to put the two arguments in a variable/array before you passed it to `echo` / `scp`. You merely seem to have "over-quoted".

Comment: yes, i just found out that. I put the arguments in a variable to check/control what is passed to scp, as i suspected a problem with quotes/spaces/etc

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> “When running outside script, command runs flawless. When running in script, it's giving error and takes only last part after space.”

What shell script are you using? What is your [shebang (`#!`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))? This all sounds like your command works in Bash but your script is running a generic shell.

So I would recommend that you make the first line of your script this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

That will make the script run via Bash and the `-l` ensures it runs with your user’s environment variables. So your script will look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

find /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/ -regex '.*\.\(vmx\|nvram\|vmsd\|vmdk\)$' ! -name *-flat.vmdk | while read line; do
    dir1=$(dirname "${line}"| sed 's/ /\\ /g')
    dir2=$(dirname "${line}"| sed 's/ /\\\\ /g')
    ssh -n root@XX.XX.XX.XX "mkdir -p $dir1"
    cmd=$(echo $line "XX.XX.XX.XX:\""$dir2"/\"")
    echo $cmd
    scp -pr $cmd
done
```

Comment: I use bash, forgot to mention (it's not in paste)

Comment: Well, a hundred appologies.... It seems your question indicated the problem... I always used bash and i wasn't paying attention on the shebang of the script (which i copied with a part of the script from vmware forums). It seems on ESXi hosts (VMware) there is no bash. Only a type of bourne shell (busybox), therefore all the strange behaviour. I'll start over. All your info is VERY precious and helped a lot. When i'll finish, i'll post the final version of my script.

Comment: @Costin Happy to help! And welcome to the world of… BusyBox! If you found my answer to be helpful, please be sure to upvote it and if it’s the answer that solved your problem, please remember to check it off as such.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this platform and i don't know much about it. Is there a way to mark an answer as helpful ? Because another user gave me the complete solution (the whole script) that worked flawless and i already gave him the mark as answer. But you were also very helpful, and i would like to mark that...

Comment: @Costin You upvote answers that are helpful and check off answers as answers if they are the answer that solved the problem.

Comment: i just found that :) i upvoted your answer as helpful. Thanx again. This problem is solved, but my script still doesn't work as expected... I opened another question to the final issue

Comment: :(( sorry, it seems my vote doesn't count :( "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."