# use find command for recursive conversion using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, find

How can I use the following script to **recursively** convert a directory containing `.mp4` to `.png` (1 frame only).

Right now it only converts the directory.  It's not recursive.

```
for i in *.mp4
do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
echo "$name"
ffmpeg -i "$i" -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:1024 -vcodec png "${name}.png"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec sh -c '
    name="${1%.*}"
    echo "$name"
    ffmpeg -i "$1" -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:1024 -vcodec png "${name}.png"
' find-sh {} \;
```

Notes:

- In your original code `` name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1` `` is rather low quality fragment. It cuts at the first dot, this seems wrong. It's not the only problem but I won't elaborate. If you want to remove an extension, the right way is `name="${i%.*}"`.
- `*.mp4` is quoted because of [this](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).
- Mind [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).
- `find-sh` is explained [here](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690).
- `find` descends into subdirectories but it doesn't follow symbolic links by default. If all "subdirectories" in `.` are if fact links to directories then you may erroneously think the tool doesn't descend in general. Check `man 1 find`, `-L` option.

Comment: hold on sir... you may have just won my personal award.

I'm testing this on the larger directory

Comment: I was reading your command "mind" this link - i'm familiar with the post - as I think I was looking in that direction.

Please wait - as I have to setup a temporary "storage spage" and use the copy command before I'm able to test this solution.

However - it worked perfectly (twice) on my sample directory structured as /a/1/2/3/

Comment: congratulations sir - you the winner of my personal award!

Comment: @user2179760 Is [acceptance](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) not included?

Comment: it certainly is.
please let me figure out how to properly "accept" your answer from within this Forum.
i will complete this task for you.

I already "upvoted your answer"  please let me know if there are other steps

Comment: @user2179760 [To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) I suggest reviewing answers to your other questions; maybe some of them deserve to be accepted. A question can have at most one accepted answer at any given time.

Comment: hello @kamil I have accepted your answer.
congratulations, you have won my "personal award"  send a priv message for personal thank you

Comment: > I suggest reviewing answers to your other questions; maybe some of them deserve to be accepted

all my other questions were asking for the same solution.

I will do as follows:

"answer my own question" with your answer, and reference your answer (this one) as a "source" .

I'm thinking this is good for both of us, because I (with 11 points) get more points and you with (38k points) get them too.