# locate fails to find files from a custom database file

Tags: linux, database

I am attempting to create a database index of a USB-drive using updatedb. I am using locate and updatedb version 0.26, on Linux Mint 20.3 using kernel 5.14.0-1042.

On the root directory of the USB drive, I ran

```
updatedb -l 0 -o test.db
```

creating test.db in the directory /media/user1/ARCH_04/.

And then I tried doing a search of this database for a file I know exists on the USB drive; the file in question has the path `/media/user1/ARCH_04/2901506_Rawdata/2901506_ReadMe.txt`

Running `locate -d test.db 2901506*` produces no output. I thought the -d flag of the locate command was supposed to conduct the search using the provided database - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing to try (and certainly a right thing to do) is to quote xor escape the asterisk, like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/432690).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I see what I did wrong - I neglected to use the -U flag to only scan the subtree rooted to the USB drive itself.

The correct command I should have used was:

```
updatedb -l 0 -o test.db -U .
```

running this command in the root directory of the USB drive.