# Why doesn't this unzip all my files in a given directory?

Tags: linux, bash

Why doesn't this unzip all the zip files in a given directory?

```
find -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} + \;
```

Instead I get "caution: filename not matched:" for each matching item

Comment: zip already zipped files?

Comment: fwiw i find xargs easier to reason about: ```find -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 unzip```

Comment: just to be clear, you want to ignore .ZIP and .Zip, you only want .zip right? otherwise you probably want `-iname` instead of `-name`

Answer (score 28):

#### Analysis

> ```
> find -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} + \;
> ```

This command itself is invalid on the level of `find`, it doesn't even get to a point where `unzip` runs. A valid `-exec` action inside a `find` command is terminated either by `+` or by `\;`*, not by both at the same time. Your description matches the behavior of the action terminated by `+` only, so I assume this was the command you really used:

```
find -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} +   # still wrong
```

> Why doesn't this unzip all the zip files in a given directory?

Because `unzip` expects exactly one zip file. Additional operands are interpreted as "archive members to be processed" (see `man 1 unzip`), i.e. files you want to extract from the archive. By using `-exec unzip {} +` you invoke `unzip` with possibly multiple arguments from the expansion of `{}`. All arguments but the first are interpreted as archive members to be processed, but you don't want them to be treated as such.

---

<sup>* Strictly: `;`. The backslash in `\;` is just to escape `;` *in a shell*, so the shell does not treat `;` as command terminator. The shell strips the backslash and `find` sees `;` as it should.</sup>

---

#### Solution

Use `-exec unzip {} \;` instead. This form will replace `{}` with exactly one pathname. It will spawn more `unzip` processes than `-exec unzip {} +` would, but each `unzip` will get exactly one zip file to process and this is what the tool expects.

```
find . -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;
```

I explicitly specified `.` as the starting path to make the answer portable. Your `find` apparently uses `.` by default, but some implementations of `find` require at least one path in the command line. `-type f` is in case some directory (or a socket etc.) matched `-name "*.zip"`; in general it may.

---

#### Example

Imagine there are `./foo.zip` and `./bar.zip` as the only matching files. `find -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} +` will execute:

```
unzip ./foo.zip ./bar.zip
```

(or `unzip ./bar.zip ./foo.zip`). This command will try to extract `./bar.zip` from `./foo.zip` (or the other way around, respectively). This is not what you want to do.

On the other hand `find -name "*.zip" -exec unzip {} \;` will execute:

```
unzip ./foo.zip
unzip ./bar.zip
```

or the same pair of commands in reverse order. This is what you want to do.

---

#### Note

The order in the above example is not specified. In practice [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/181815) is basically true:

> `find` will be traversing the directory tree in the order items are stored within the directory entries. […]

In theory `find` is *not required* to traverse in this order, it just happens it's a convenient order to implement.

Anyway, in your case if files extracted from one zip collide with files stored in another zip then at some point `unzip` will ask you what to do. Pay attention to what archive the question is about; do not assume any particular order of archives.

Answer (score -4):

In addition to Kamil's excellent answer, there's a more insidious problem here: the use of double quotes rather than single quotes around `*.zip`will allow expansion to happen during execution of the find command.

Consider the following example:

- You have abc.zip in the `.` directory
- There are one or more subdirectories containing files such as def.zip, ghi.zip, etc.

When the find command executes, the shell expands `*.zip` to be `abc.zip` effectively making your command execute as `find -name abc.zip -exec . . .` -- this is probably not what you want.

Comment: -1. This is not true. Single- or double-quotes prevent `*` from being expanded by the shell. If the asterisk in `*.zip` was unquoted then [yes, this could be a problem](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/432690). In the question there is `"*.zip"`, the asterisk is quoted, it's totally OK.

Comment: Double quotes allow variables and command substitutions to be expanded, but not wildcards.

Comment: However, as a matter of style, I recommend using single quotes except for strings that contain variables that should be expanded. So I always put the `-file` argument in single quotes for clarity.