# Highlight filename in "find" command

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have this command which works great

```
find . -type f -name *.txt -exec grep -li blah {} \;
```

Let's say the output will be:

```
/tmp/folder1/file1.txt
/tmp/folder2/myfile.txt
/tmp/thisfile.txt
```

If I was to do this:

```
find . -type f -name *.txt -exec grep -li -E --color blah {} \;
```

this would highlight the entire string.  So `/tmp/folder1/file1.txt` would be highlighted.

Can I get it to highlight only the filename?  So `file1.txt`, `myfile.txt`, `thisfile.txt` will be highlighted and nothing else.

Is this even possible?

Comment: The command "works great" until [this happens](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

Answer (score 3):

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
```

---

So, find does not do `\x1b` or `\e`, then let us help...

```
$ find -type f -maxdepth 2 -printf "%h/§[1m%f§[m\n" | sed -re 's/§/\x1b/g'
```

In `man find` you will find(!) more of those `%<character>` thingies.
They define what you want to have printed.

Here `%h` prints the first portion of the path, and `%f` the last portion of it (which usually is the filename) ...

***NOTED:***

```
$ find -type f -maxdepth 2 -printf "%h/$(tput bold)%f$(tput sgr0)\n"
```

... this is "nicer" as it will be terminal-type agnostic (as long as tput, *ncurses-bin* is installed); as is:

```
$ find -type f -maxdepth 2 \  
-printf "%h/$(setterm --reverse on)%f$(setterm --reverse off)\n"
```

Ref: `man termifo` for "bold" and similar, or even `man setterm` (from util-linux) as a replacement for `tput`

Comment: This answer is partial. The OP wants to colorize the output of `grep -l`. The answer can be fixed thanks to the fact `-exec` is also a test in `find` and `grep -q` works well in such test. `find -type f -maxdepth 2 -exec grep -qi blah {} \; -printf "%h/§[1m%f§[m\n" | sed -re 's/§/\x1b/g'`

Comment: The answer might be considered "partial", yes - but brings to front *the main thing* asked for. Look, i saw the tree in the forest.

Comment: I think GNU find supports `find -printf '\033'`. Or in Bash and others you could use `find -printf $'\x1b'`

Answer (score 0):

This is a general-purpose filter that highlights text from the last `/` in a line to the end of the line. If there is no `/` then the whole line will be highlighted. Trailing `/` characters are treated like non-`/`.

```
highlight() (
if [ -t 1 ] || [ "$1" = -f ]; then
   start="$(tput bold)"
   end="$(tput sgr0)"
   sed "s|[^/]*./*$|$start\\0$end|;t;s|.*|$start\\0$end|;"
else
   cat
fi
)
```

Examples:

1. ```
   highlight <<EOF
   dir/dir/file
   dir/dir/
   dir/dir/////
   no-slash
   /
   .
   EOF
   ```
2. ```
   find . | highlight
   ```
3. ```
   grep -lr . | highlight
   ```

Notes:

- The filter can take input from `find`, `grep` or *anything*. The filter does not rely on non-portable `find -printf`.
- `tput bold` and such are not portable though. Adjust `start=` and `end=` to your needs.
- Inside the `sed` code `|` is used as a delimiter for `s`. It's crucial not to have `|` from the expansion of `$start` or `$end`. Adjust to your needs. Remember `s` in `sed` can use almost any character as delimiter.
- The filter tests if its stdout is a terminal. If not, it becomes `cat` (i.e. a no-op filter). You can force highlighting even to a non-terminal with `highlight -f`. Example:

  ```
  find . | highlight -f | head -n 3
  ```