# Linux file search: fdfind command vs. fdz command

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I'd love to use the `fdz` command to search for files on a Linux system, the presentation of `fdz` results is much more pleasant. But there's something I need to resolve first. An example will be much more explicit than a written explanation.

If I want to find all the files in the `/home/user directory` whose name contains the word "jacques", I can use the `fdfind` command or the `fdz` command:

```
:~$ fdfind -H jacques
.thunderbird/<profile>/Mail/Local Folders/ex-mm.sbd/divers.sbd/jacques
.thunderbird/<profile>/Mail/Local Folders/ex-mm.sbd/divers.sbd/jacques.msf
Documents/jacques
Documents/jacques/feuille de soins jacques 001.pdf
PDF/feuille de soins jacques 001.pdf

:~$ fdz -a jacques
./Documents/jacques/
./.thunderbird/<profile>/Mail/Local Folders/ex-mm.sbd/divers.sbd/
 ├ jacques
```

As you can see, the second command leaves out a lot of relevant answers. Even with `fdz --help` I can't find the right options to make the `fdz` command give the same results as the `fdfind` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
:~$ fdz -a '*jacques*'
./Documents/jacques/
 ├ feuille_de_soins_jacques 001.pdf
./PDF/
 ├ feuille_de_soins_jacques_001.pdf
./.thunderbird/<profile>/Mail/Local Folders/ex-mm.sbd/divers.sbd/
 ├ jacques.msf
 ├ jacques
```

Comment: Quote the asterisks. Compare to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).